# ignore element for page size calculation

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions

How to force browser NOT to calculate the size of the content based on some absolute positioned elements?
I am looking for something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-stack-sizing

For a simplistic use case please view http://jsfiddle.net/edzis/5nnYk/

```
html, body, .container {
    /**
        https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-stack-sizing
        DOES NOT WORK
    **/
    -moz-stack-sizing: ignore;
    -webkit-stack-sizing: ignore;
    stack-sizing: ignore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an exact match to what you are looking for, but maybe it can present some ideas.

If you can change the html code, you could make use of "overflow: hidden" by using a second absolute positioned layer and let the "container" div only be responsible for the dimensions where you want to have scrolling.

NB: There is a possible issue here if the initial window width is small and the container causes scrolling, the elements off screen may not be rendered and will require refreshing.

Here's an updated jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/5nnYk/24/

code e.g:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class='left'>LEFT</div>
    <div class='right'>RIGHT</div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

Then set the panel class to:

```
.panel{
    width:99%;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

BTW: I set width to 99% instead of 100% because it fixes another issue that sometimes rises and causes a horizontal scroll. Another way to solve this is use left: 0px; on the panel.